# How to download arXiv article PDF files and TEX files in "Other formats" (if they exist)?

Tags: webservices, serviceexecute

I find that `ServiceConnect` can access much arXiv information. But is it possible to download the PDF/TEX files I want, e.g., given article `"ID"`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To download PDF's for a list of article ID's:

```
ids = {"1707.04849v1", "0904.3664v1", "1707.09562v3", "1507.02188v1"};
arXiv = ServiceConnect["ArXiv"];

pdfURLs = Flatten[arXiv["Search", {"ID" -> ids}][All, "Link"]][Select[#Type == "application/pdf" &]][All, "Href"];

URLDownload[#, Last[URLParse[#]["Path"]] <> ".pdf"] & /@ Normal[pdfURLs];
```

Files are downloaded to your home directory. To download to a different location, modify the second argument to `URLDownload`

Comment: @Αλέξανδρος Did my answer help? If so, please accept it, if not let me know why so I can improve the answer. Thanks!